# App falhando quando uma imagem é selecionada

Tags: java, android

Eu estou tentando obter uma imagem usando um Intent, mas quando eu seleciono a imagem, o meu aplicativo fecha imediatamente. Este é o meu código atual:

```
private void capturarFoto() {

    String nameFoto = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();

    caminhoFoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),nameFoto);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(caminhoFoto));
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Ele deve chamar o  método `onActivityResult` após a seleção de imagem, mas infelizmente fecha sem nenhum erro na Logcat.

Tem alguma coisa errada?

**LOGCAT**
[image: LOGCAT]

Comment: Sempre que possível poste o texto do logcat. Esta imagem é praticamente ilegível.

Comment: Eu testei seu trecho de código e funcionou normalmente. Verifique se o trecho `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` não retorna null. Só um detalhe que achei é que o seu arquivo não tem extensão, mas isso não deve influenciar.

Comment: Obrigado, irei Verificar.

Comment: @ExceptionAl até concordo contigo, texto do logcat é melhor, mas a imagem não está ilegivel, é o SO que reduz a imagem para caber no layout. Basta clicar com o mouse e salvar ela.

Comment: Você testou em mais de um device ou somente no emulador? Alguns telefones (não lembro exatamente quais agora) retornam null para essa chamada.

Comment: A chamada `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` pode realmente retornar nulo. Mas, isso pode acontecer quando o aparelho não possui um _ExternalStorage_ configurado ou habilitado. Para evitar o resultado nulo, chame `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)` para saber se é possível acessar o _ExternalStorage_. Mais informações podem ser encontradas na página de [desenvolvedores do Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Answer (score 1):

Para voce poder capturar uma imagem pela camera, voce deve primeiro criar uma intent pelo codigo semelhante ao seu :

```
private static final CAMERA=1; //o actionCode que voce usara no onActivityResult
private void intentParaTirarFoto(int codigoDePedido) {
    Intent intentParaTirarFoto= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intentParaTirarFoto, codigoDePedido);
}
```

Depois disso no metodo on ActivityResult voce faz:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int codigoDePedido, int resultado, Intent dados) {

    super.onActivityResult(codigoDePedido, resultado, dados);

    if(codigoDePedido==CAMERA && resultado==getActivity().RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapImage=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    //apartir daqui voce pode gravar a imagem ou fazer alguma outra coisa com o bitmap
                  gravarImagem(bitmapImage);

    }

}
```

abaixo a implementacao do codigo para gravar a imagem no celular:

```
private void gravarImagem(Bitmap bitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file;
    File minhaPasta= new File(root + "/Pictures/Testando"); 
    Date date=new Date();
    long timeStamp=date.getTime();
    if(!myDir.exists())
    {
        myDir.mkdir(); //cria uma nova pasta caso a espicificada acima nao exista
    }
    String nomeFicheiro= "TestandoCamera"+timeStamp+".jpg";
     file= new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("GRAVOU", "IMAGEM GRAVADA NO CELULAR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você está acessando o **getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);** acredito que você esteja acessando esse código através de um Fragment. Note que como você está chamando esse método via Activity, você deve esperar que o **[onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)** da sua Activity seja chamada e não o **[onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)** do seu Fragment. Pode verificar isso? Pelos dados informados, é o que dá pra deduzir.